# Making AES encryption identical between Android and iOS

Tags: ios

In Android app and Java back end I am using this code to encrypt password. But in iOS I and not able to generate the same encrypted password in iOS. iOS I have tried using FBEncryptorAES. code is given below. But the key in Java is generated using 'SecretKeySpec' class which is not available in iOS. Please let me know any similar class is there in iOS for generating same key.

for 
NSString *password=@"payroll2";

in iOS I am getting pHsCp3RtM8vGtMr6MShaSg==

in Java I am getting jGJv8CfhKDUAhaiGdgJHXA==

```
private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = 
            new byte[] { 'a', '/', '5', '0', '0', '2', '*', 'l', '+', 'O', '&','@', 'b', '~', '_', '$' };

    //For encryption
    public String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        String encryptedValue ="";
        try{
        SecretKeySpec key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (java.security.Key) key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
            return encryptedValue;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedValue;
    }


 //Generate Secret Key
    private static 




 generateKey() throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }
```

iOS code..

```
 unsigned char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128] = { 'a', '/', '5', '0', '0', '2', '*', 'l', '+', 'O', '&','@', 'b', '~', '_', '$' };
 NSData *dataKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:keyPtr length:sizeof(keyPtr)];

    NSString* encryptedPassword = [FBEncryptorAES encryptBase64String:password
                                                    keyString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)keyPtr]
                                                separateLines:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using FBEncryptorAES I created two categories one for NSString and one for NSData. NSString+AESCrypt.h and NSData+AESCrypt.h
code is given below.  From the given set I generated the key as below

```
 unsigned char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128] = { 'a', '/', '5', '0', '0', '2', '*', 'l', '+', 'O', '&','@', 'b', '~', '_', '$' };
   NSString* encryptedKey =   [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)keyPtr];
```

and encrypted the given string using the following code :

```
 NSString *encryptedString = [password AES128EncryptWithKey:encryptedKey];
```

Class definition is as follows :

NSData+AESCrypt.h definition :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (AESCrypt)

-(NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
-(NSData *)AES128DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;

+(NSData *)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;
-(id)initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;

-(NSString *)base64Encoding;
-(NSString *)base64EncodingWithLineLength:(NSUInteger)lineLength;

-(BOOL)hasPrefixBytes:(const void *)prefix length:(NSUInteger)length;
-(BOOL)hasSuffixBytes:(const void *)suffix length:(NSUInteger)length;

@end
```

NSData+AESCrypt.m

```
#import "NSData+AESCrypt.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
/*
static char encodingTable[64] =
{ ‘A’,’B’,’C’,’D’,’E’,’F’,’G’,’H’,’I’,’J’,’K’,’L’,’M’,’N’,’O’,’P’,
    ‘Q’,’R’,’S’,’T’,’U’,’V’,’W’,’X’,’Y’,’Z’,’a’,’b’,’c’,’d’,’e’,’f’,
    ‘g’,’h’,’i’,’j’,’k’,’l’,’m’,’n’,’o’,’p’,’q’,’r’,’s’,’t’,’u’,’v’,
    ‘w’,’x’,’y’,’z’,’0′,’1′,’2′,’3′,’4′,’5′,’6′,’7′,’8′,’9′,’+’,’/’
};
*/

static char encodingTable[64] =
{
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'
};

@implementation NSData (AESCrypt)

-(NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // ‘key’ should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That’s why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted );
    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess ){

        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}

-(NSData *)AES128DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // ‘key’ should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That’s why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted );

    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark –

+ (NSData *)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [[NSData allocWithZone:nil] initWithBase64EncodedString:string];
}

-(id)initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableData *mutableData = nil;

    if( string )
    {
        unsigned long ixtext = 0;
        unsigned long lentext = 0;
        unsigned char ch = 0;
        unsigned char inbuf[4], outbuf[3];
        short i = 0, ixinbuf = 0;
        BOOL flignore = NO;
        BOOL flendtext = NO;
        NSData *base64Data = nil;
        const unsigned char *base64Bytes = nil;

        // Convert the string to ASCII data.
        base64Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        base64Bytes = [base64Data bytes];
        mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:base64Data.length];
        lentext = base64Data.length;

        while( YES )
        {
            if( ixtext >= lentext ) break;
            ch = base64Bytes[ixtext++];
            flignore = NO;

            if( ( ch >= 'A' ) && ( ch <= 'Z') ) ch = ch - 'A';
            else if ( ( ch >= 'a' ) && ( ch <= 'z') ) ch = ch - 'a' + 26;
            else if ( ( ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9') ) ch = ch - '0' + 52;
            else if ( ch == '+') ch= 62;
            else if (ch == '=') flendtext = YES;
            else if ( ch == '/' ) ch = 63;
            else flignore = YES;

           /* 
            if( ( ch >= ‘A’ ) && ( ch <= ‘Z’ ) ) ch = ch – ‘A’;
            else if( ( ch >= ‘a’ ) && ( ch <= ‘z’ ) ) ch = ch – ‘a’ + 26;
            else if( ( ch >= ‘0’ ) && ( ch <= ‘9’ ) ) ch = ch – ‘0’ + 52;
            else if( ch == ‘+’ ) ch = 62;
            else if( ch == ‘=’ ) flendtext = YES;
            else if( ch == ‘/’ ) ch = 63;
            else flignore = YES;
            */

            if( ! flignore )
            {
                short ctcharsinbuf = 3;
                BOOL flbreak = NO;

                if( flendtext )
                {
                    if( ! ixinbuf ) break;
                    if( ( ixinbuf == 1 ) || ( ixinbuf == 2 ) ) ctcharsinbuf = 1;
                    else ctcharsinbuf = 2;
                    ixinbuf = 3;
                    flbreak = YES;
                }

                inbuf [ixinbuf++] = ch;

                if( ixinbuf == 4 )
                {
                    ixinbuf = 0;
                    outbuf [0] = ( inbuf[0] << 2 ) | ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x30) >> 4 );
                    outbuf [1] = ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x0F ) << 4 ) | ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x3C ) >> 2 );
                    outbuf [2] = ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x03 ) << 6 ) | ( inbuf[3] & 0x3F );

                    for( i = 0; i < ctcharsinbuf; i++ )
                        [mutableData appendBytes:&outbuf[i] length:1];
                }

                if( flbreak )  break;
            }
        }
    }

    self = [self initWithData:mutableData];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark –

-(NSString *)base64Encoding
{
    return [self base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
}

-(NSString *)base64EncodingWithLineLength:(NSUInteger)lineLength
{
    const unsigned char   *bytes = [self bytes];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:self.length];
    unsigned long ixtext = 0;
    unsigned long lentext = self.length;
    long ctremaining = 0;
    unsigned char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];
    unsigned short i = 0;
    unsigned short charsonline = 0, ctcopy = 0;
    unsigned long ix = 0;

    while( YES )
    {
       // ctremaining = lentext – ixtext;
        ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
        if( ctremaining <= 0 ) break;

        for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            ix = ixtext + i;
            if( ix < lentext ) inbuf[i] = bytes[ix];
            else inbuf [i] = 0;
        }

        outbuf [0] = (inbuf [0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
        outbuf [1] = ((inbuf [0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inbuf [1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
        outbuf [2] = ((inbuf [1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((inbuf [2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
        outbuf [3] = inbuf [2] & 0x3F;
        ctcopy = 4;

        switch( ctremaining )
        {
            case 1:
                ctcopy = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                ctcopy = 3;
                break;
        }

        for( i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++ )
            [result appendFormat:@"%c", encodingTable[outbuf[i]]];

        for( i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++ )
            [result appendString:@"="];

        ixtext += 3;
        charsonline += 4;

        if( lineLength > 0 )
        {
            if( charsonline >= lineLength )
            {
                charsonline = 0;
                [result appendString:@"\n"];
            }
        }
    }

    return [NSString stringWithString:result];
}

#pragma mark –

-(BOOL)hasPrefixBytes:(const void *)prefix length:(NSUInteger)length
{
    if( ! prefix || ! length || self.length < length ) return NO;
    return ( memcmp( [self bytes], prefix, length ) == 0 );
}

-(BOOL)hasSuffixBytes:(const void *)suffix length:(NSUInteger)length
{
    if( ! suffix || ! length || self.length < length ) return NO;
    return ( memcmp( ((const char *)[self bytes] + (self.length - length)), suffix, length ) == 0 );

    //(self.length – length)
}
@end
```

NSString+AESCrypt.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSString+AESCrypt.h"

@interface NSString (AESCrypt)

-(NSString *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
-(NSString *)AES128DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

NSString+AESCrypt.m

```
#import "NSString+AESCrypt.h"
#import "NSData+AESCrypt.h"


@implementation NSString (AESCrypt)

-(NSString *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *plainData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *encryptedData = [plainData AES128EncryptWithKey:key];

    NSString *encryptedString = [encryptedData base64Encoding];

    return encryptedString;
}

-(NSString *)AES128DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:self];
    NSData *plainData = [encryptedData AES128DecryptWithKey:key];

    NSString *plainString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return plainString;
}


@end
```